# How to get the bearer token in the Asp .Net Core SignalR Hub?

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, microservices, bearer-token, asp.net-core-signalr

I need access to the bearer token raw string (the token itself) in the Asp.Net Core SignalR Hub.

I need it because i have to use it when I'm making HttpClient Call to other microservice that requires the token from my hub.

I tried to create Per-request service that has Token property, but SignalR does not use Per-Request pattern. The token is sent only when client is connecting, and not always.

Anyway I need to get access to the bearer token and don't know how.
Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I need access to the bearer token raw string (the token itself) in the Asp.Net Core SignalR Hub.

If you configure and use [bearer token authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-3.1#bearer-token-authentication) for your ASP.NET Core SignalR App, to access the token that client provided within your hub method, you can try:

```
 var accessToken = Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Query["access_token"];
```

Test Result

[image]